# How do I calculate the angle of a right triangle using the Javascript Math library?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

Consider the following triangle :

[image]

I want to calculate angle **X**

I have the following :

```
    var opposite = 2.5;
    var hypotenuse = 5;

    var sinOfAngleX = opposite / hypotenuse; // 0.5
```

So now I know that `Math.sin(valueofAngleX)` would return `0.5`.

But how do I get the value of an angle if I know the sine of the angle, using the Math() library?

According to [this tutorial](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html), I need to do :

var angleX = *`sin to the power of negative one of 0.5`*

but I don't know how to translate that into JS.

I tried :

```
var angleX = Math.pow(Math.sin(sinOfAngleX), -1);
```

but it returns **2.085829642933488** which is obviously wrong. The correct answer should be **30**

And in case all of the above is wrong to begin with, does anyone know how I can calculate angle X correctly using the JS Math() library?

Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, it looks like you're taking the sine of the sineOfAngleX, which is wrong to start with. (thanks whoever -1'd me, I meant that to be a comment rather than an answer)

Comment: `sin^-1(a)` here does not mean `1/sin(a)`, but rather `"the inverse function of sin"(a)`, thus arcsin (a.k.a. `asin`). To write `1/sin(a)` with `^-1`, one would add parenthesis : `(sin(a))^-1`. Note that `sin(a^-1)` means `sin(1/a)`, and `sin(a)^-1` is ambiguous, thus should be avoided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can know the angle of any sin with this formula:

```
Math.asin(sinOfAngleX) * 180/Math.PI
```

With `sinOfAngleX = 0.5`, `Math.asin(sinOfAngleX)` would give `0.5235987755982989`. This is expressed in radians. To pass it to degrees you can multiply by `180/Math.PI`, which results in 30º

Answer (score -1):

In ES6 you can use the build it method from `Math` Object

```
 Math.hypot(3, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Good code trick, however, that actually gives you the length of the hypotenuse, not the angle asked for in the OP.